# New row leaving space in MUI Grid system

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, material-ui, grid, grid-layout

In the following image the blue block is rendered under the red and green blocks. I would like the blue block to render directly underneath the red block.

Is there a way to achieve this with MUI grid?

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";

export default function BasicList() {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item alignContent="center" justifyContent="center" md={6}>
          <Box style={{backgroundColor:"red"}} height={200}>
            MD = 6 Height = 200
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item md={6}>
          <Box style={{backgroundColor:"green"}} height={600}>
            MD = 6 Height = 600
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item md={6}>
        <Box style={{backgroundColor:"blue"}} height={200}>
            MD = 6 Height = 200
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put both Red and Blue boxes together as one grid. something like this can solve the problem:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";

export default function BasicList() {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item alignContent="center" justifyContent="center" md={6}>
          <Box style={{backgroundColor:"red"}} height={200}>
            MD = 6 Height = 200
          </Box>
          <Box style={{backgroundColor:"blue"}} height={200}>
            MD = 6 Height = 200
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item md={6}>
          <Box style={{backgroundColor:"green"}} height={600}>
            MD = 6 Height = 600
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Each grid can be responsible for a column in your design.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, it does solve but i would also like when the screen is small the sequence should be red-green-blue in that order, basically responsiveness of all 3 gird items comes into picture. Is there a way to do it without adding into single grid item?

Comment: in MUI and React, there is a property called "order" in which you can set the orders in response to the size of the page. something like: <Grid xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={4} order={{ xs: 3, sm: 2 }}>